# Swift Retrieve Data with Nested Array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to pass data into variable by displaying it(NameList and BasketDetail). But the basket data is empty(BasketDetail). How can i solve this (Output:Retrieve data: [“name”: Mike, “basket”: <__NSArray0 0x28112c060()])?

Firebase node;

```
"Pro_" : {
  "-MsVcfY7pZI74r0E1ULD" : {
    "basket" : {
      "-Mruf-UdXxpLK0l8Qgw4" : {
        "cat" : "Tech",
        "info" : "iOS",
        "orderid" : "Ref_1",
      },
      "-MszuLj3cxm_gE9m-VPO" : {
        "cat" : "Tech",
        "info" : "Android",
        "orderid" : "Ref_2",
      }
    },
    "name" : "-Mike",
  }
}
```

My function;

```
private func populateNameLists() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.ref.child(“Pro_”).observeSingleEvent(of:.value) { (snapshot) in
        self.nameLists.removeAll()
        let nameListDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
        for (key,_) in nameListDictionary {
            if let nameListDictionary = nameListDictionary[key] as? [String:Any] {
                if let nameList = NameList(nameListDictionary) {
                    self.nameLists.append(nameList)
                    print(“Retrieve data:”, try! nameList.toDictionary())
                }}}}}
```

Output(Basket's empty ???)

> Retrieve data: [“name”: Mike, “basket”: <__NSArray0 0x28112c060()]

Name List

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]
class NameList : Codable {
    var basket :[BasketDetail] = [BasketDetail]()    
    var name: String!

    init(name:String ) {
        self.name = name
    }
    init?(_ dictionary :[String:Any]) {
        guard let name = dictionary[“name”] as? String else {
            return nil
        self.name = name
        let basketItemsDictionary = dictionary[“basket”] as? [JSONDictionary]
            if let dictionaries = basketItemsDictionary {
                self.basket = dictionaries.compactMap(BasketDetail.init)
            }}}
```

Basket Detail

```
class BasketDetail : Codable{
    var cat : String
    var info : String
    var orderid : String
    init(cat :String, info :String, orderid :String) {
        self.cat = cat
        self.info = info
        self.orderid = orderid
    }
    init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {
        guard let cat = dictionary["cat"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let info = dictionary["info"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let orderid = dictionary["orderid"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        self.cat = cat
        self.info = info
        self.orderid = orderid
    }}
```

Comment: Instead of the schematic depiction of your database, can you edit your question to show the actual JSON? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I edited the node, Frank. Do you have any ideas for solution?

Comment: Hmmm... at first glance the code and data structure seem to match up, so I'm not sure what's going wrong. I'm not a Codable expert though, so I hope somebody else spots it.